# Booting up Rails api and Angular2 app with single command for local development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I have our back-end api app running separately from our front-end Angular driven instance.

Basically two different apps:

1. Rails api runs on unicorn
2. angular app that runs on Apache web server

We might add more dependencies to our stack such as Redis or anything else. How do I start everything at once? Without having to start everything else individually in the separate console tabs?

What I've found so far that could do something similar is (pow.cx), I just don't know how I would configure it to run Apache web server along with my api, that's why I'm kind of asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to merge the both in rails application. But Usually API & FrontEnd should be on different servers. So, What's the solution if you have Mobile-App send the request to this API. I don't think you can start the mobile App & rails App once?

You can handle format HTML & JSON in rails actions (To handle rails application & API), then merge Angular App with Rails App as the following:

You should add `app` directory of angular 2 to `public` folder in rails folder. Also, Load `node_modules` folder in `class Application` as the following:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

Change routes of angular 2 to the same port of rails server:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api').subscribe( 
data => this.message = data.json().some, err => console.log(err) );
```

I suggest to read this to help you:

[Integrate Angular 2 with rails](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/react-vs-angular-2-integration-with-rails).